# Twitter User Lookup Request Error Confusion

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitterapi-python

I have **activated** my app after getting approval of my Twitter developer account. I am trying to get twitter account associated with an email/phone number using **Twitter Api**.
It works perfect with params like **screen_name**,**user_id** but while trying email or phone number as a param the

**Response** says :

**Could Not Authenticate you**

Code is

```
import requests

url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?map=true&phone=1234567890"
payload = {}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'OAuth realm="http%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com",oauth_consumer_key="<consumer_key>",oauth_token="<outh_token>",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1595318479",oauth_nonce="<nonce>",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="<sig>"'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Response :

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 32,
            "message": "Could not authenticate you."
        }
    ]
}
```

What are the reasons and suggestions on this ?

Will appreciate the positive feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using dynamic values generation for header like **nonce** generation, **Timestamp**, base_url according to query paramters?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use email or phone number as query parameters on the Twitter API. This is not supported as a feature in the API. See the documentation for supported parameters on [users/lookup](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-lookup) and [users/search](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-search).

Comment: Yeah i know email/phone search is no more mentioned in twitter's official documentation but it was in 2015 documentation. Also the the route is working as I have captured the network call from android and the same request is working with the parameters but when I change the params like email/phone it gives this error. This request is working perfectly fine but may be i am missing some parameter or something like that. But with the same parameters, Tokens.

Comment: I've reviewed our documentation going back to 2013 and these parameters have never been available on this endpoint. If you're trying to reverse engineer something inside a Twitter app, then this is against the Twitter Developer Policy and Terms of Service - use the official API. There is no way to use email or phone number to look up Twitter users in the API.